Changing from one LDAP provider (FreeIPA) to another (Active Directory) without creating new accounts
We currently use a self-hosted Phabricator for internal ticketing. It is mounted in a container with it's own database (MariaDB).
To enable our users to access it we historically have an LDAP connection to a FreeIPA server we also self-host. With recent changes we are now using Active Directory, and we are slowly swapping from one to another. This is where we encounter issues.
When changing it, in some cases we are unable to connect anymore without getting a problem with the existing accounts : Either the mail is already in use so the connection is refused, or we are offered to create a new account, or it creates a second account. In Phabricator case we receive this message :
Email Address Already in Use

You are creating a new account linked to an existing external account.

The email address ("XXXXX@XXX.XX") associated with the external account is already in use by an existing Phabricator account. Multiple Phabricator accounts may not have the same email address, so you can not use this email address to register a new account.

If you want to register a new account, continue with this registration workflow and choose a new, unique email address for the new account.

If you want to link an existing Phabricator account to this external account, do not continue. Instead: log in to your existing account, then go to "Settings" and link the account in the "External Accounts" panel.

If you continue, you will create a new account. You will not be able to link this external account to an existing account

How could we proceed to either fuse the accounts together, or change some attributes/search filter to match both accounts ?
On a general aspect we are open to any informational ressources about LDAP/AD on Linux or within containers.
For the moment I tried to understand what was not matching between both accounts, without success. My guess is that the full DN are different as the OU organizations are different. I wondered if matching the attributes we use for each to be the same would solve the issue, like instead of importing the full DN, to only import the login name (which is the same on both).
